# display random template in wordpress footer.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display one random wordpress template out of 3, for pages with slugs beginning with "b". I have this code:

```
$current_page = sanitize_post( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );

$slug = $current_page->post_name;

$slugBeginsWith = substr($slug, 0, 1);

if($slugBeginsWith == 'a')
{
    get_template_part( 'templates/template1' );
}
elseif($slugBeginsWith == 'b')
{
    $table = array(get_template_part( 'templates/template1' ), get_template_part( 'templates/template2' ), get_template_part( 'templates/template3' ));
    echo $table[array_rand($table)];
}
```

hovewer this gets me all 3 displayed at once for pages with "b" slugs. How do I correct this?

Comment: strange... try `echo $table[array_rand($table), 1];` - although it should be 1 by default

Comment: now it breaks the footer, I updated whole code if that matters